# How to include all files (including ones in subfolder) in sourcepath of a JAVA project?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a Java project on VS Code, and I wish to add all of the files inside the `src` folder. Layout of the project:

[image: layout]

As you can see, there are multiple subfolders inside `src`, and I wish to add all of them in the `java.project.sourcePaths` inside the `settings.json` file so the files can run. If I leave it as `"java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],`, I got errrors which my objects created `cannot be resolved to a type`.

I got this temporarily fixed by changing the direcotry into `src/PA 1/`, but I do not know how to include all subfolders of `src`. This means everytime I create a new subfolder, I need to come back to add it in `java.project.sourcePaths`.

Is there a way to include all subfolders inside `src`? I tried `src/**/` but it did not work.

PS: Can any one explain why Java is not recognizing files inside the subfolder?

Comment: In a Maven project, all source files should be in `src/main/java`, under their package path, e.g. if your file is in the package `com.yoururl.frontend` then it should be in the folder `src/main/java/com/yoururl/frontend`.

Comment: @JFabianMeier This does not look like a Maven project.

Comment: @JFabianMeier This is not a standard Maven project and I am using the default packages.   When I created the project, I used the tool from VS Code's command panel. Ctrl+Shift+P to jump to the panel, then I typed ```create java project```, and selected the one with ```No Build Tools```.

Comment: @Aaron3963 So why did you tag this question with Maven? Anyway, a project should have only one source folder. If you want to order your Java classes, use Java packages.

Comment: The real answer: don't do that. Follow the maven standard directory layout, do not use default packages. Seriously, when you are in Rome, do like the Romans do. Especially when you are learning a new language, don't do things "your way". Try to stay with "the standard way" all the time, and only deviate when you have really good reasons to do so. That implies you understand the standard, and why it is really better for you to do sth else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to add all the subfolders of `src` to `"java.project.sourcePaths"`. `"java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"]` is enough.

The codes under the subfolders of `src` should be structured by the `package` and `import`, both relative to `src`.